# How can I get .Replace() to work from a text file?

Tags: python, replace

im trying to replace all the periods, and commas from a text file the .lower works perfectly find only .replace isn't working

```
def clean_text(text):

    for line in text:
        line= text.replace(".", "")

        line= text.replace(",", "")
        
        line=(text.lower())
    print(line)
```

Comment: You're assigning to `line` three times, then you print `line` outside of the loop. The net effect is that only the lowercase of the last line of the file will print. Did you mean to use `line` inside the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
line= text.replace(".", "")
```

That code creates a new variable `line` which is a copy of `text` without periods.

```
line= text.replace(",", "")
```

That code erases the previous contents of `line` and recreates it as a new variable which is a copy of `text` without commas.

```
line=(text.lower())
```

That code erases the previous contents of `line` again, and recreates it as a new variable which is a lowercase copy of `text`.

So, your problem is that you're making variables and then throwing them away, undoing your work.

Perhaps you meant to do this instead:

```
line= text.replace(".", "")
line= line.replace(",", "")
line=(line.lower())
```

Note how the last two statements refer to `line` instead of `text`, so the work done by the previous statements is preserved.